# VB.Net - data does not show up in database grid and does not update the ms access database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, vba

I am making a database program where users can add their data such as lrn, first name, middle name, and last name. My data sources are fine and the table loads in data grid view but when I run the program and enter new data, they do not show up in the data grid nor the access file

Here is the code :

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    Dim poi As DialogResult
    poi = MessageBox.Show("Do You Want To Exit?", "Exit Program?", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel)
    If poi = DialogResult.OK Then
        Application.Exit()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'BoboDataSet.Table1' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.Table1TableAdapter.Fill(Me.BoboDataSet.Table1)

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Table1BindingSource.AddNew()
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    'this button users click that will transfer the user's inputted data to the data grid viewer and updates the database
    Table1BindingSource.EndEdit()
    Table1TableAdapter.Update(BoboDataSet.Table1)
End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Table1BindingSource.RemoveCurrent()
End Sub
```

End Class

I am a bit stumped! I think there is a wrong configuration in my data source but I followed steps to enter it and I already changed the database property to Copy if Newer but the new data entered does not show up in the database grid viewer and the access file

Thanks for the response :)
*Edited to better reflect my problem, Hopefully

Comment: "i cant add anything"...and "the add works fine". These two statements appear to contradict each other. Can you be a bit clearer about what is happening please? Also what debugging have you done exactly? Precisely where is your code failing? Are you getting errors, or some other unexpected flow of the code? You say you "can't" do something (but then appear to contradict yourself), but don't explain what is happening instead.

Comment: Im sorry if i am not abit clear. For example when the user inputs something to the text box such as their information, when they click save button which is the button 3 click. The data should appear in the datagrid view, but it appears on the database grid view as blank. I have done anything such as changing the primary key to lrn and making sure both label and the database is the same word. But now the error says along the lines of "lrn.Table1 is blank"

Comment: The flow of the program is the user presses add new button (which is button 1), the users enter their lrn, first name, middle name, surname, their gender (from the combo box) and their birthday (from the dateandtimepicker) and press save which is the button 2 and the entered data will show up in the datagridview and the access file.

Comment: The flow of the program is the user presses add new button (which is button 1), the users enter their lrn, first name, middle name, surname, their gender (from the combo box) and their birthday (from the dateandtimepicker) and press save which is the button 2 and the entered data will show up in the datagridview and the access file. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

At last! I have fixed the problem. The textboxes were not binded to the table in the data bindings. I just changed in the data bindings section in the textbox properties. sorry for the inconvenience